# Ionic React Add SideMenu to Ionic Blank page

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a `loginpage` and i want to create a dashboard page that has a sidemenu, i'm confused on how to create the route using react-router in the `app.tsx`

```
app.tsx

<IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
```

I want `Dashboard Page` to contain SideMenu, which can be a component i will import to dashboard page.

Is there a fix around this, the solutions i have seen so far is for Angular, what of React?

Comment: need to see more code?

Comment: I will edit the post now sir